# Why does collision function won't remove an enemy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove enemies when they get hit by a bullet, but as i can see this doesn't work.
I am writing this in codehs worksheet (javascript bootcamp).

```js
var char;
var bullet;
var enemy;
var life = 5;
var enemyTimer = Randomizer.nextInt(0,50);
var enemies = [];
function start(){
    makeChar();
    keyDownMethod(movements);
    makeBullet();
    setTimer(shootBullet, 30);
    addEnemy();
    setTimer(makeEnemy, 5);
    checkCollision();
}
function makeChar(){
    char = new Circle(10);
    char.setColor(Color.red);
    char.setPosition(getWidth()/2, 430);
    add(char);
}
function movements(e){
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        char.move(10,0);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        char.move(-10,0);
    }
}
function makeBullet(){
    bullet = new Rectangle(5,10);
    bullet.setPosition(char.getX(), char.getY());
    bullet.setColor(Color.green);
    add(bullet);
}
function shootBullet(){
    bullet.move(0,-10);
    if (bullet.getY() < 0){
        bullet.setPosition(char.getX(), char.getY());
    }

}
function makeEnemy(){
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i ++){
        var b = enemies[i];
        b.move(0,5)
        b.move(Randomizer.nextInt(-3,3),0);

    }

}
function addEnemy(){
    setTimer(en,800);
}

function en(){
    enemy = new Rectangle(50,50);
    var x = Randomizer.nextInt(10, 350);
    var y = enemy.getY();
    y += 10;
    enemy.setPosition(x,y);
    add(enemy);
    enemies.push(enemy);
}
function intersects(a,b){
    return (a.getX() < b.getX() + b.getHeight() && a.getX() + a.getWidth() >b.getX() && a.getY() < b.getY() + b.getHeight() && a.getY() + a.getHeight() > b.getY());
}
function checkCollision(){
    for(var i =0; i < enemies.length; i++){
        var en = enemies[i];
        if (intersects(bullet, en)){
            println("hi");
            remove(en);
            i--;
            remove(bullet);
        }
    }
}
```

With print I tried to see if it did read collision but it did not even print it.
I want it to remove enemies when it gets hit by a bullet, 
Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you provide a working example using jsFiddle or any similar tool?

Comment: i dont really know the language yet. when i tried to put the code in there it gives me an error about Randomizer, and i dont really know how to change it...

Comment: What is Randomizer ?

Comment: so it gives u random number between ones u put in there. Its built in function on that bootcamp

Comment: In JsFiddle you can change it to function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

Comment: i tried to do it but it only shows white screen

Comment: Of course it will, it doens't add anything to the DOM, what is add() ? I am sorry the code is not clear and your question is not comprehensible.